# Binding a generic to a function

Tags: typescript, firebase

Say I have the following function (and interface):

```js
interface IDocument {
  id: string;
  data: () => any;
}

function addId<T>(doc: IDocument) {
  return { id: doc.id, ...(doc.data() as T) };
}
```

And then I want to pass this function *with the generic value set* as a callback to `map`.

```js
interface IClient {
  name: string;
}

myDataArray.map(addId);
```

**My question is:** Is there a way to tell TypeScript that the invoked `addId` has a `T` set to `IClient`?

I tried:

```js
myDataArray.map(addId<IClient>);
```

But got the following:

```
Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.ts(2554)
add-id.ts(2, 3): An argument for 'doc' was not provided.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one?

```
myDataArray.map(item => addId<IClient>(item));
```

Comment: No way to do this without creating another function though?

Comment: I don't know... Anything else that I can think of is even more complicated. Is there any solid reason to avoid the extra function?

Comment: Not really, just asking out of interest